# Xcode IOS - How to get the scene/view that is currently being viewed in appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Okay I am kind of new to IOS development, but I am writing an application where I am using a timer class to time out the user if they idle too long on any particular scene in my storyboard and it bumps the user back to the original scene/view.  I have a single story board that is made up of several scenes/views(not sure what the correct word here is), and each scene has its own view controller.

I accomplish the timeout via the appdelegate class.  See code below.

So I have the code working and it works great, but I am trying to make it so that it will ignore the timer if we are on the main scene.

I have googled this, read copious amounts of documentation, and have tried many things but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to get the currently viewed scene in the applicationDidTimeout method.

If I can get the name of the currently viewed scene/view, then I can choose to ignore the timer or not.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you for your time.

```
#import "StoryboardAppDelegate.h"

#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"

@implementation StoryboardAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

    // applicaiton has timed out

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:) name:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];

    return YES;

}

-(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif

{

    NSLog (@"time exceeded!!");



    UIViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardViewController"];



    UINavigationController * navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];



    [self.window setRootViewController:navigation];

    navigation.delegate = self;

    navigation.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    if (controller) {

        @try {

            [navigation pushViewController:controller animated:NO];

        } @catch (NSException * ex) {

            //“Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported”

            //NSInvalidArgumentException

            NSLog(@"Exception: [%@]:%@",[ex  class], ex );

            NSLog(@"ex.name:'%@'", ex.name);

            NSLog(@"ex.reason:'%@'", ex.reason);

            //Full error includes class pointer address so only care if it starts with this error

            NSRange range = [ex.reason rangeOfString:@"Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported"];



            if ([ex.name isEqualToString:@"NSInvalidArgumentException"] &&

                range.location != NSNotFound) {

                //view controller already exists in the stack - just pop back to it

                [navigation popToViewController:controller animated:NO];

            } else {

                NSLog(@"ERROR:UNHANDLED EXCEPTION TYPE:%@", ex);

            }

        } @finally {

            //NSLog(@"finally");

        }

    } else {

        NSLog(@"ERROR:pushViewController: viewController is nil");

    }

    [(TIMERUIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] resetIdleTimer];

}

@end
```

Comment: Well one way I know of getting the "currently viewed view" is getting the top window. You can do that by saying UIViewController *topView = self.window.subViews[0];

Comment: Okay so when I access topView in debug mode and check out its properties, it isn't really giving me any useful information that I can use to identify it.  Its title is nil for example.

Once I have topView what do I need to do with it to figure out which scene I am on?

Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have come up with a solution and will post it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've written the logic for the timer somewhere. Can you just invalidate the timer when you've popped back to the rootViewController?

Also instead of pushing a viewController onto the navigationViewController and handling the errors, you should check to see if the controller you're pushing is already in the stack like so:

```
if (![navigation.viewControllers containsObject:viewController] {
   // push onto the stack
}
```

You could also check to see how many levels are currently in the navigationController by checking the count of the viewControllers array like so:

```
if ([navigation.viewControllers count] == 0) {
   // I know we're on the main screen because no additional viewControllers have been added to the stack.
}
```

Comment: Yes.  The logic is written in a class file, and start it to run in main.m. I will try your ideas out, and get back to you.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#import "StoryboardAppDelegate.h"

#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    @autoreleasepool {

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([TIMERUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([StoryboardAppDelegate class]));

    }

}

Comment: When I get the number of viewcontrollers it is always 1 it seems and never 0.  I guess this may be because I am programmatically declaring the navigation controller?

Also I want to avoid invalidating the timer as that is kind of a tricky thing to manage and would like to if possible permit it to continue ticking throughout the entire life cycle of the application.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating a new NavigationViewController each time the app times out? Is that what you want? Perhaps you need to store the navigationViewController as a property and keep pushing/popping from its stack.

Comment: Yeah I am willing to bet you are correct.  I don't really know too much about how to use them and this was some nice code I found to where I didn't have to set up things in the development environment.

Do you know any articles or code examples where I could get some ideas from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using modal controllers anywhere then the simplest solution would be

```
UINavigationController* nav = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController; // You could just save the nav as part of your app delegate
if (nav.viewControllers.count > 1){
  [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This is different then your current code because your main page will not be deleted and recreated every time the timer goes off

Comment: When I try to get the count using the code you used I get an exception "Unrecognized selecter sent to instance UIViewController".

So I modified what you told me and used my navigation instance to invoke the count property and the count is always equal to 1 in my code regardless of what scene I am on.

Maybe I have architectured my application incorrectly; I am very new to this.

Any more thoughts?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just figured out an easy workaround for this problem.  Since I just joined today it won't let me post solution until tomorrow.

I will post my solution tomorrow.  =) 

Thanks to all of you for your help.

It is funny going from coding in .net to doing mac IOS dev work.  So different, but I really love it, it just takes time to understand a new way of doing things.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out how to do this.  I was making this way too complicated.

To solve this I simply made a property and method in the app delegate class where I could set a scene name.

Then in each view controller header file I import the header file for the app delegate class and define a reference to it.  Then in the load event for each view I simply set the scene name in the app delegate class using this line of code.

[myAppDelegate setSceneName:self.title];

Easy peasy!